# solving inhomogeneous second-order equation(forcing term)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I am given a second order differential equation 
>   $y''+7y'+6y = 3 \sin(2t)$ and asked to solve for particular solution.

Picked $y_p=a \cos(2t)+b \sin(2t)$
then plugging into the original equation, I arrive at 
$$(2a+14b)\cos(2t)=(14a-2b+3)\sin(2t)$$

I was told to solve for this equation
$\begin{cases} 2a+14b=0,   \\14a-2b+3=0, \end{cases}$
to get $a$ and $b$.

> I was told that we can pick any arbitrary $t$ but I still don't know why they can be set equal to $0$ at the same time.

Comment: Is there a typo in the problem where $t$ is not there? You have two equations and two unknowns - use Gaussian Elimination, Substitution, .... You should get $$a = -\dfrac{21}{100}, b = \dfrac{3}{100}$$

Comment: @Moo thanks for catching that. But why can we set both equations to 0?

Comment: $$(2a+14b)\cos(2t)=(14a-2b+3)\sin(2t)$$
This must be true for all t thats why you set the coefficients ( of the sine and cosine functions) equal to zero.

Comment: It's true for $t=0$, and it's true for $t=\pi/4$. That gives your two equations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you can post as answer

Comment: OK, done, spruce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $$(2a+14b)\cos2t=(14a-2b+3)\sin2t$$ holds for all $t$. When $t=0$, you get $$2a+14b=0$$ When $t=\pi/4$, you get $$0=14a-2b+3$$